# Alternative Query Tuning

Tags: sql, oracle, query-optimization

i have tried to fetch the data, but its taking long time to fetch, Table JOIN_DATA has millions of records, please correct me, if i did something wrong on below query

```
with SUM_VALUE AS 
  (
  SELECT INS, SUM(BAL)
  FROM JOIN_DATA
  GROUP BY INS 
  HAVING SUM(TRIM(BAL)) <> 0
  )
,
  
  GET_KEY AS 
  (
  SELECT  KEY, SUM(TRIM(BAL)) FROM JOIN_DATA
  WHERE INS IN (SELECT DISTINCT INS FROM SUM_VALUE)
  GROUP BY KEY
  HAVING SUM(TRIM(BAL))<> 0
  )
  
  Select distinct key from GET_KEY
```

Comment: Why do you have `TRIM(BAL)` - is BAL a VARCHAR2?  It should be a NUMBER if you are going to SUM it, in which case no TRIM is needed.

Comment: @TonyAndrews good catch, ya i have to correct

Comment: At a minimum, we'd need to see the query plan and we'd need to know what you consider a "long time".  How quickly are you trying to get the query to run?  Blindly, I'd question why you're doing a `trim` (a string function) on a value you're summing (a number).  I'd guess that you'd be better off with an `exists` rather than an `in` and getting rid of both `distinct` operations since the wouldn't appear to impact the results.  You could probably do this in one pass with a couple of analytic functions but I'd want to better understand exactly what you're trying to implement.

Comment: @JustinCave those SUM function taking lot of time even after few filter i have applied to reduce the dataset

Comment: Hence why I'm asking what the query plan is, what "long time" means to you, and what performance you're trying to achieve.  If you're aggregating 100 million rows and you want the query to return in a couple seconds, you're probably out of luck.  If you're aggregating a million or two on decent hardware and it's taking hours to run, there is a whole lot of room for improvement but we'd need to see the plan to see where things are going wrong.

Comment: @JustinCave i want to try some alternative query thats why i have posted this

Comment: Without knowing the plan and your expectations, and without a reproducible test case, blindly guessing at other ways to write the query is unlikely to be very beneficial to you.  There are lots of ways to write a query.

Comment: @JustinCave just give me some sample i'm newbie without using with clause

Comment: Remove the two `distinct` clauses.  That changes the query.  I don't believe it changes the results.  Maybe it'll affect performance.  Maybe not.  Without seeing the query plan, you're asking people to guess blindly at what might be causing you problems.  As I said in my initial comment, you could try changing the `in` to an `exists`.  Maybe that'll make things faster.  Maybe not.  Maybe it will for a day and you'll be back to poor performance in a day or a week or a month.  Not knowing the plan, we have no idea.

Comment: Trying to diagnose a performance problem without minimal information like a query plan is a lot like telling your mechanic that you've got car trouble and asking for things to try without giving any symptoms.  Maybe you ran out of gas.  Maybe you need an oil change.  Maybe the parking brake is still on.  Maybe your battery is dead.  Maybe there was an oil leak and the engine is a big ball of fire.  You might guess luckily.  But more likely you'll spend a lot of time stumbling around without accomplishing much.

Comment: @JustinCave ok bro thanks for your advice, i will have to learn what is query plan and how to check and what i need to change and all

Comment: Please [read this](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/query-optimization/info). It explains what we, and you, need to know to take on [tag:query-optimization] questions.

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing the execution plan of the statement, it is impossible to rewrite the query. However, perhaps is possible to make it faster.

- Use `parallel query`
- `Group by` and other sorting operations can have a huge boost in performance using parallel query, mostly in cases you are accessing huge amount of rows.

Keeping that in mind

```
alter session enable parallel query;

with SUM_VALUE AS 
  (
  SELECT /*+materialize parallel(a) */ INS, SUM(BAL)
  FROM JOIN_DATA a
  GROUP BY INS 
  HAVING SUM(TRIM(BAL)) <> 0
  ),
  select distinct key 
  from 
  (
  SELECT /*+parallel(b) full(b) */ KEY, SUM(BAL) FROM JOIN_DATA b
  WHERE INS IN (SELECT /*+parallel(c) */ DISTINCT INS FROM SUM_VALUE c)
  GROUP BY KEY
  HAVING SUM(TRIM(BAL))<> 0
  )
```